# How Can I change the Alpha parameter in this Material nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

I am doing animation using MakeHuman and blender in the Cycle Render mode. As mentioned this image, I try to fix materials for the skin of the person. I just need to know How can change the parameter value of alpha. Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

use the math node to modify the alpha output of the image :

[image]

Comment: I have used the search tools  but I did not find the multiply node.

Comment: @startingBlender it is called MATH node you find i in converter-->math